# Vite/SVG-loader Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module ... does not provide an export named 'default'

Tags: svg, vuejs3, vite

I'm attempting to create a nuxt3 icon component that utilizes an svg-loader, and imports a couple dozen icons from a folder using an index.ts file. The svg actually loads and renders on the page, but the browser is throwing the error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module ... does not provide an export named 'default'

The basic setup:

From icon.vue

```
<template>
  <div v-html="allIcons.angleDown"></div>
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
import * as allIcons from "./icons";
console.log(allIcons.angleDown); //Correctly logs the svg as a string. v-html above correctly renders the icon on the page.
</script>
```

from ./icons/index.ts

```
import angleDown from "./angle-down.svg?raw";
import angleLeft from "./angle-left.svg?raw";
export { angleDown, angleLeft };
```

I've also tried:

```
export { default as angleDown } from "./angle-down.svg?raw";
export { default as angleLeft } from "./angle-left.svg?raw";
```

The svg loader I'm using is vite-svg-loader. I'm attempting to model my component roughly on what's being done here: https://github.com/Kong/kongponents/blob/main/src/components/KIcon/KIcon.vue

Error message in context: Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/_nuxt/components/GlobalIcon/icons/index.ts?t=1683298764604' does not provide an export named 'default' (at components.client.mjs?t=1683298764604:6:10)

thanks for the help!